# Regex to match phone number in Arabic Text

Tags: regex

I'm using this regex to extract Phone Number in Arabic text.

I Already Tried the following **Regex**:

```
\b[+]*[(]{0,1}[0-9]{1,4}[)]{0,1}[-\s\./0-9]*\b
```

Which is not working in the case of Arabic text + Latin Phone Numbers

Input :
من الرجاء الاتصال بي على ذلك الرقم 312-555-83
I'm expecting as output : 
312-555-83

Input :
إذا كانت لديكم أية أسئلة، فيُرجى الاتصال بي، ROSE ANN MONTEMURRO، منسقة شؤون أولياء الأمور على رقم 347-563-4758 أو زيارتي في الغرفة 214
Output : 
347-563-4758

Mixed Arabic and Latin can confusing, you need to visualize it In a RTL editor.

Comment: Maybe you can do it in 2 steps? 1) Replace `[^0-9+./-]+` with a newline and then 2) extract the numbers?

Comment: I don't understand your idea @WiktorStribiżew , can you explain ?

Comment: What is the programming language?

Comment: I'm using Java.

Comment: Ok. `str = str.replaceAll("[^0-9\\s+./-]+", "\n");` then use your extracting regex approach against the updated `str`.